# GCP - Reading images in GCS into Datalab using Python

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I have a store of images in Google Cloud Storage and I am looking to read them into OpenCV in Datalab.  I can find information on how to read text files but can't find anthing on how I can read in an image.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I am not really familiar with OpenCV, so let me cover the Datalab ⟷ GCS part and I hope that is enough for you to go on with the OpenCV part.

In Datalab, you can use two different approaches to access Google Cloud Storage resources. They are both documented (with working examples) in these Jupyter notebooks: access GCS using [Storage commands](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/Storage/Storage%20Commands.ipynb) ( `%%gcs` ) or access GCS using [Storage APIs](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/Storage/Storage%20APIs.ipynb) ( `google.datalab.storage` ).

I'll provide an example using Storage commands, but feel free to adapt it to the Datalab GCS Python library if you prefer.

```
# Imports
from google.datalab import Context
from IPython.display import Image

# Define the bucket and and an example image to read
bucket_path = "gs://BUCKET_NAME"
bucket_object = bucket_path + "/google.png"

# List all the objects in your bucket, and read the example image file
%gcs list --objects $bucket_path
%gcs read --object $bucket_object -v img

# Print the image content (see it is in PNG format) and show it
print(type(img))
img
Image(img)
```

Using the piece of code I shared, you are able to perform a simple object-listing for all the objects in your bucket and also read an example PNG image. Having its content stored in a Python variable, I hope you are able to consume it in OpenCV.